# Business Process to "Transfer" a one-to-many association

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

**Introduction To Domain**

I have a Salesman. A Salesman gets BusinessOpportunity's. Both make sense in my domain to be ARs.

There are two ways to model this:

1. A Salesman aggregate is unaware of its business opportunities, or
2. A Salesman is aware of his list of opportunities (using an OpportunityId of course)

A BusinessOpportunity, I believe, always needs to know its SalesmanId.

**The Question**

I have a business process that I plan on implementing using a Process Manager pattern. It is a "TransferAllBusinessOpportunities" process. It means taking 1 salesman and "transferring" all of his/her opportunities to the other.

How should we do this? and how should we model the domain?

I can think of a process state machine if we model this as a bidirectional association, but its quite involved. I don't know how to do it if we only have a unidirectional association because we'd then need to resort to the read model to get the list of business opportunities to transfer and I'm worried that we should keep everything in the write-side model. What do you think about that?

Any help is very much appreciated. Attached a diagram below to help visualize if that helps.

[image: business process]

A quick roundup of the questions:

1. How would you tackle this problem?
2. How would you model the domain to best tackle this?
3. Is it ok to use the read model in a command handler to execute the business process?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta-answer: you need to read what Greg Young has to say about [set validation](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/08/12/eventual-consistency-and-set-validation/).  You'll be in a better position to explore your requirements with your domain experts.

> I don't know how to do it if we only have a unidirectional association because we'd then need to resort to the read model to get the list of business opportunities

Extracting the data from the read model should be your first resort.  What's the problem?

Basic outline

1. Query the read model for the set
2. Create command(s) to update the write model based on the set
3. Dispatch the commands to the write model

   - the write model gets the set data it needs from the command (*not* from the read model)

The first resort won't always satisfy your requirements, but it's a good starting point for thinking about the use case.  What problems could occur if you implemented this simple way? what would those problems cost the business?

Also: I said commend up above, but it might not be.  One thing that you didn't describe is what part of the model "decides" the transfer.  Is the model allowed to reject the command to transfer the opportunity?  Under what circumstances?  which aggregate holds the state that determines if the transfer is allowed?

It might be that the transfer isn't being described as a command, so much as it is by an event, describing a decision made by some human sales manager.

> I'm worried that we should keep everything in the write-side model

Maybe.  Is there a business invariant that needs the state of the set?  So far, it doesn't sound like it, which strongly implies that the set does not belong in the write model.  You want to strip down your aggregates as far as you can without losing the ability to enforce the invariant.

> Is it ok to use the read model in a command handler to execute the business process?

Is it "ok"?  Judging from what I have read in various places, a number of people think so.  Personally, I'm not convinced.  Roughly, you are looking at two broad outlines

1. Create a thin command
2. Send the command to the command handler
3. Query the read model to flesh out the missing details
4. Process the fleshed out command

vs

1. Query the read model
2. Use the query results to construct a fat command
3. Send the command to the command handler
4. Process the command

I've yet to see an example where the business would care about the distinctions between these two implementations; the latter implementation is easier to predict (you don't need to know anything about the state of the read model, just the state of the aggregate and the state of the command).

Comment: Thanks @VoiceOfUnreason this is very insightful. Do you find it ok to do a $repository->save($bo) on multiple BO ARs in a single command handler? I've been trying to keep it simple and only do one AR/transaction per command handler. It would be convenient to query the read model and loop through all of the BOs during a single command handler, persisting each one. Otherwise, I am doing a lot of messaging/listening to handle the business process (and it's all within the same BC, anyway). Thoughts?

Comment: "Do you find it ok to do a $repository->save($bo) on multiple BO ARs in a single command handler?"  No -- if the contention that introduces is acceptable, why are these things separate aggregates?

Comment: When I query the read model I get a list of, for example, 20 BusinessOpportunityIds. These needs to be transferred so I can make 1 fat command saying "transfer(BoList, otherSalesman)" which would need 20 updates on each of these separate aggregates. Or should I instead issue 20 commands each with one AR? i.e., "transfer(BO, otherSalesman)" x 20?

Comment: One command to each aggregate responsible for enforcing the invariant.  Otherwise, you have a problem with one (or more) BusinessOpportunities reject the transfer (which is really suspicious -- is this question/problem trying to hint to you that your domain model is wrong?)